# What are the physical properties of momentum space?

Tags: black-holes, momentum, neutron-stars

*In classical mechanics, the phase space is the space of all possible states of a physical
system; by “state” we do not simply mean the positions q of all the objects in the
system (which would occupy physical space or configuration space), but also their
velocities or momenta p (which would occupy momentum space)*

quoted from: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/phase_space.pdf

In black hole formation via collapse the stellar matter is compressed so all possible position states are filled which means by virtue of Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle that momentum space must increase exponentially. This would create a highly unusual physical situation. What properties would this have?

Comment: it sounds like you want to ask something about momentum space, but you never clearly formulate the question

Comment: @lurscher - thank you. I've tried to formulate a good question now but the internet is very sparse on beginners information about momentum space so I'm hoping someone with a special interest in the subject may see this.

Comment: possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524720/955

Comment: There is some very clear information in this answer which should take you a long way: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/258467/248459